# Why was this question of mine closed?

Tags: discussion

Why on earth was this question of mine closed?

[Do I need a comma in "Здравствуйте вновь!"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23212/do-i-need-a-comma-in-%d0%97%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8c)

No dictionary contains an answer to my question.